# Measures to overcome Fortran timer wraparound

Tags: time, fortran, gfortran

The Fortran intrinsic `system_clock` can be used to measure the wall clock time (useful for parallel computations). I read [here](http://www.idris.fr/eng/su/shared/fct_95-eng.html) and [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/g77_371.html) that `system_clock` and `cpu_time` will return negative values if the functionality is not available, *or* "due to insufficient ranges offered by the underlying system's timers".

I'm experiencing this problem in simulations that run for several weeks and, suddenly, negative values are reported.

So my question is, what measure can I take to avoid or overcome these insufficient ranges / negative returned values? I would show a first attempt at overcoming this problem, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Do you use 8 bit integers at least?

Comment: Since f2003 large integer arguments have been supported in system_clock.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm actually did not specify a default selected_int_kind so, I think, the an 8 bit integer (default) was used. Is using a large integer a viable solution to overcoming this issue?

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after elapsed wall clock time over a time period of weeks, then the DATE_AND_TIME intrinsic will generally provide values with sufficient resolution.

(SYSTEM_CLOCK should not suddenly start reporting negative values - either an image has a clock, or it does not.  What the count returned by SYSTEM_CLOCK might do is wrap, from the value given by COUNT_MAX back to zero.)

Comment: This solution, which I did not think of, is certainly now on my radar. However, the comment by Vladimir suggests that system_clock may still work with proper use and, since this intrinsic was designed with timing in mind, I will likely use this approach if it proves to be a solution. Regardless, I appreciate your suggestion, and may come back to it.